# How to print vowels in a word?

Tags: c++

Without the use of array or vectors or functions! ... Solving this from the c_for everyone textbook.

Question - Write a program that reads a word and prints the number of vowels in the word. For this exercise, assume that **a e i o u y** are vowels. For example, if the user provides the input "Harry", the program prints 2 vowels

Attempt -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout <<"Please enter a word" ;
char alpha;
cin>> alpha; 
int count = 0;


for ( int i=0; i <= alpha.length(); i++)
{
if (alpha == 65 || alpha == 69 || alpha == 73 || alpha == 79 || alpha == 85 || alpha == 89)
    count++;
}

cout << count << " vowels." ;


return 0;
```

Shows this error and doesn't compile  -  p.4.13.cpp:15:27: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it's from the `c_for everyone` textbook, shouldn't this be tagged C, not C++?

Comment: congrats for the attempt. Do you have any question?

Comment: `char alpha;` is a single char. Also avoid magic numbers like `65`, use `'a'` instead.

Comment: Shows this error -->  p.4.13.cpp:15:27: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union

Comment: Instead of `char alpha;` it should be `std::string alpha;` Also, instead of `for ( int i=0; i <= alpha.length(); i++)`  it should be `for ( int i=0; i < alpha.length(); i++)`

Comment: @SaulGoodman `alpha.length();` primitive types have no member functions.

Comment: @sameerkn No, that's also wrong.

Comment: `Word` is a collection of one or more `letters` so you cannot use a `char`.

Comment: @sameerkn Sure you can.  You just have to read the word character by character which is what the exercise is trying to teach to the OP.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't think this assignment expects reading word character by character.  :)  Although we can.

Comment: @sameerkn The only choices the OP has is to use a char array of a fixed size(which has to be bigger than all possible inputs) or they can read character by character.  Since all they have to do is count and display the number of vowels there is no reason to use an array asthe OP does not need the word afterwords.  That makes reading character by character the natural solution.

Comment: Always wondered why some people seem to think "'a'? I have no idea what that gibberish means. I'll write 65 instead, it makes much more sense." Perhaps one day science will explain it.

Comment: @NathanOliver -  So is there any way I can make the user enter the word in one line? Also if we read character by character, how would I incorporate a for loop? Again thanks for your help people!

Comment: @NathanOliver: Reread the question and yes, reading word character by character is expected.

Comment: So how would the code look like then? If I say "Fantastic", that means I need to have 10 cin commands?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, but just trying to post something as close to your original I could do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

const string vowels{ "aeiouy" };
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    std::string alpha;
    getline( cin, alpha, '\n' );
    int count = 0;

    for( const auto& letter : alpha ) {
        if( string::npos != vowels.find( letter ) ) ++count;
    }

    cout << count << " vowels.";

    cout << '\n' << '\n';
    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using std::string(or an array of chars, char[]) instead of char, "char" is a primitive type, it is not a struct and have no member that you can access through the "." operator.